# How do I web scrape a specific column in a table?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying web scrape a list of basketball players in a specific column. I can get the first player but no one else after that. I need to get the entire list of players in string form. Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}   

url = ("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2011.html")
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

header = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit = 99)[1].findAll('th')[1:]]
header[2]
player = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(rows))]
player[1][2]
```

The output of player[1][2] is 'Kyrie Irving' which means I am on the right track, but I need to get all the players in the column. I tried doing player[::][2] but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player name is present inside a `<td>` with the attribute `data-stat` equals to `player`.

Select all the `<td>` with the above attribute using `findAll()` and extract all the players names from each `<td>`.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2011.html'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

players = soup.findAll('td', attrs= {'data-stat': 'player'})
                 
for i in players:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see rows assigned anywhere. You could simply use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to target the players by the value of their `data-stat` attribute:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2011.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
players = [i.text for i in soup.select('[data-stat=player]')][1:]   #attribute selector
```

You could also use an `:nth-child()` selector:

```
players = [i.text for i in soup.select('td:nth-child(4)')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

url = ("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2011.html")

table = pd.read_html(url)[0]

players_name = table[('Round 1',  'Player')]

for player in players_name:

     print(player)
```

output:

Kyrie Irving

Derrick Williams

Enes Kanter

Tristan Thompson

Jonas Valančiūnas

.

.

.
.

Comment: You need to filter on an additional column as this will also print headers along with player names.

Answer (score 0):

Just let pandas parse the table (filter out the non names), then put it in a list:

```
import pandas as pd 
 
draft_df = pd.read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2011.html")[0]
player_list = list(draft_df[draft_df['Rk'].ne('Rk')]['Player'])

print(player_list)
```